# Is it possible to run a SparkR program in Spark without R interpreter installed?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

My question is about the feasibilty of running a sparkR program in spark without an R dependency.

In other words can I run the following program in spark when there is no R interpreter installed in the machine?

```
#set env var
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/home/fazlann/Downloads/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6")
#Tell R where to find sparkR package 
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"),"R","lib"), .libPaths()))

#load sparkR into this environment
library(SparkR)

#create the sparkcontext 
sc <- sparkR.init(master = "local")

#to work with DataFrames we will need a SQLContext, which can be created from the SparkContext
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

name <- c("Nimal","Kamal","Ashen","lan","Harin","Vishwa","Malin")
age <- c(23,24,12,25,31,22,43)
child <- c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)

localdf <- data.frame(name,age,child)

#convert R dataframe into spark DataFrame
sparkdf <- createDataFrame(sqlContext,localdf);

#since we are passing a spark DataFrame into head function, the method gets executed in spark
head(sparkdf)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. You'll need to install R and also the needed packages, otherwise your machine won't know that she needs to interpret R.

Don't try to ship your R interpreter in the application you are submitting as the uber application will be excessively heavy to distribute among your cluster.

You'll need a configuration management system that allows you to define the state of your IT infrastructure, then automatically enforces the correct state.

Answer (score 0):

No. SparkR works by having an R process communicating with Spark via rJava. You will still need R installed on your machine, just as you need a JVM installed.

Comment: I think they got rid of rjava in the latest release. Now they communicate via sockets

Comment: Even thought they communicate via sockets, you'll still need to install the R interpreter